# Is `std::format` vulnerable to format string attack? How to mitigate it?

Tags: c++, printf, c++20, format-string, fmt

I would like to refactor C style code using `printf`, `fprintf`, etc... to C++. Is `std::format` vulnerable to format string attack, as the aforementioned C functions?

If I search for format string attacks, all I find is [stdio format string vulnerabilities](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Format_string_attack). I would like to know more about if `std::format` is vulnerable, and how to mitigate it, even if I have to format user provided strings.

Comment: After reading the documentation, where would you suspect such vulnerabilities?

Comment: `std::format` has *strict* checks on the format string, if they are not legal, they will be rejected *at compile-time*.

Comment: @康桓瑋 rejecting at compile time a user-provided format string seems hard to implement :-D (the format strings are read in at run time)

Comment: @6502. No, after [P2216](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2216r3.html#checks), the format string passed into `std::format` must be a constant expression, otherwise, it will be ill-formed. Runtime strings are *only* supported by `std::vformat`.

Comment: @康桓瑋: you're right, that is nice enforcement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would like to know more about if `std::format` is vulnerable, and how to mitigate it, even if I have to format user provided strings.

Even if you use [`std::vformat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/vformat) (which accepts a run-time string), the input is verified against the types of the other arguments and `std::format_error` is raised upon mismatch (while `std::format` verifies this at the call site during compile time).

So a malicious user cannot sneak in a format specifier for an argument you did not provide. And since the formatter that is used for an argument must be based on its static type (and so also provided by you), an attacker cannot try punning.

All in all, that vector of attack seems blocked.

Answer (score 4):

`std::format`, like `printf`/etc., assumes that the format string is from a trusted source. A malicious format string for `std::format` can't usually cause the same specific problems as one for `printf`/etc. (implicit type punning, buffer overruns, etc.), though `std::format` has some customization support which potentially enables such problems (and others).

If you want to use `std::format`, then you need to make sure that the format string is OK, either by writing it yourself or by validating that it has the specific form you expect.

Comment: I appreciate that you mention the possible side-vulnerabilities (e.g. DoS by malicious format specifiers? I'd be interested to know whether some mitigations have been put into place, but I guess it all comes down to the QoI of custom formatters)

Answer (score 3):

The C functions like `printf` use [variadic arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments), which don't provide any means to detect types and amount of the arguments actually passed. The only way `printf` can tell is by examining the format string. If this string lies, you have UB.

On the other hand, `std::format` is a templated function where all the types and amount of the arguments are known at compile time. It does know what each type is and, moreover, it checks at compile time that the string matches the types. Same for `std::vformat`, which does know the types in the same manner (using the information in its `std::format_args` parameter), and does check validity of the string, although at runtime.

Thus, attacks of this kind, i.e. with malicious strings, are defied.